# What are these round brackets for after variable name?

Tags: c++, declaration, brackets, initialization

```
const int headerSize (0x130);
std::string GenFileName ( argv[1] );
```

"(0x130)" and "( argv[1] )" are incomprehensible for me why they are there because I never seen type+name+() declaration.

Comment: These are called direct initialization: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

Comment: Note that it is generally preferred to use [uniform initialization syntax](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) (using `{}` instead of `()`) because it can help prevent the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: in case of `string` it just calls the constructor with a single argument. In case of `int` it does initialization of the variable in a constructor-like syntactic manner.

Comment: Thank you for the information !

Comment: One of the commenters should post an answer.

Comment: And what is the difference between normal and direct initalization ?